# Allow web user to add a new raster layer to the OWS service

Tags: ows

Suppose that we have a web application that is showing a basemap. We want to allow users to upload their raster file into the server and server shows the new added raster file automatically after upload is done. Is it possible?

If yes, which OGC standard protocol should I use (WMS, WFS, WCS)?

Comment: "Is it possible?" in IT question is almost always answered with yes. But this quite a complex problem, the standard software and protocols do not allow this. But there exist ready Web applications that can include user-contributed data. Have a look at GeoNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Your OGC weapon of choice should be [Web Coverage Service - Transactional](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/13-057r1/13-057r1.html) (WCS-T)

Comment: Thank u, which map server is implementing WCS-T? Geoserver? Mapserver? ArcGIS server?

Comment: I know WCS-T is supported by [rasdaman](http://rasdaman.org/), other software may also support it.

Comment: do u think rasdaman is suitable for commercial projects?

Comment: There is a commercial version of Rasdaman, and a community version, so the answer should be yes.  You would need to contact Rasdaman to discuss your needs to get a definitive answer.